# MySQL - SELECT until fixed number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to ask for help because I am not able to execute a `SELECT` statement in `MySQL`.

The `SELECT` should return 350 lines, as long as the first lines are filled according to a specific condition and if there is space left, the rest is filled with another condition.

Comment: could you please post what you have right now

Comment: I suggest you first change the requirement to, say, 12 lines instead of 350, and then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expressions in the ORDER BY clause, and a LIMIT clause.

For example:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER
    BY IF(( t.foo >= 117 AND t.bar IN (2,3,5) ),0,1)
     , IF(( t.foo >= 0                        ),0,1)
     , IF(( t.bar = 42                        ),0,1)
     , ...
 LIMIT 350
```

Rows that satisfy the condition `t.foo >= 117 AND t.bar IN (2,3,5)` will be ordered first. (Because the ORDER BY will operate on the return from the expression. That condition will be evaluated, and the IF function will return either 0 or 1. The subsequent expressions in the ORDER BY clause will be evaluated in the same way.

The LIMIT clause will restrict the number of rows returned, but doesn't guarantee that the query won't return *fewer* rows e.g. if mytable contains fewer than 350 rows.

Comment: Hi spencer! Thank you for your help! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: More ANSI compliant would be using a CASE expression in place of the MySQL-specific IF() function... e.g. `ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.foo >= 117 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
SELECT column(s) FROM TABLE WHERE column = 42 LIMIT 350
```

Or do you want the first line where 'column = 42' and then read 350 lines?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your help! But I was looking for the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You limit the number of returned rows with `LIMIT`. You use `ORDER BY` to say which rows you prefer.

Let's say you are looking for records where col = 'best', but if there are not enough (i.e. 350) you also want rows with col = 'okay':

```
select *
from mytable
where col in ('best', 'okay')
order by case when col = 'best' then 1 else 2 end
limit 350;
```

Comment: Hi Thorsten! Thank you for your help! But I was looking for the answer above.

Comment: Well, actually spencer7593 and I gave you about the same answer: use the `ORDER BY` clause with conditions to achieve what you want. `IF` is MySQL only, `CASE` is standard SQL.